# Export middleware auth function, out of file with passport configuration in Express.js & Discord OAuth2

Tags: javascript, express, discord, passport.js, middleware

I am writing an application with Discord OAuth2 provider. I have used the passport and passport-discord libraries. I have created middleware to check auth and now I want to export it to use in other files. I can't.

index.js :

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const DiscordStrategy = require('passport-discord').Strategy;

// Configuration
app.use(session({
  secret: 'super-secret-session-code',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

// Init Passport.js
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Config Discord OAuth
const discordStrategy = new DiscordStrategy({
  clientID: '<MyClientId>',
  clientSecret: '<MyClientSecret>',
  callbackURL: 'http://192.168.0.4:3001/auth/discord/callback',
  scope: ['identify', 'email']
}, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {

  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(discordStrategy);

// Serialise and deserialise user
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});
```

And this function, that works only in `index.js`:

```js
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  //res.redirect('/auth/discord');
  res.sendStatus(401)
}
```

`req.isAuthenticated()` - this line works only in this file, and I can't even export that function to other file...

When I tried to import it to other file with:

`const isAuthenticated = require('./index').isAuthenticated`

or with `module.exports = ...`

And used it as middleware:

`router.use('/dashboard', isAuthenticated, dashboard)`

I got an error:

`Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`

Maybe this is a bug that stems from my unfamiliarity with JavaScript, but if anyone can help me out, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: Where are you calling `Route.get()`

Comment: It is just an error message that refers to the `router.get('/anything', isAuthenticated, anything);`

Comment: Then `anything` or `isAuthenticated` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Yes, and my question is how to import this as a function that will work

Comment: Can you first find which of the two is undefined?